# Would a short-lived temp file avoid actual disk io?

Tags: linux, io

I have a linux server on AWS that is hosting a postgres database server and a nodejs api server. It has 240GB RAM, and major portion is dedicated to the database. Approx 32GB is the memory is left open to the OS to deal among the 
app server, various OS-level caches, and whatever need arises. There is no explicit fsync. The database + indexes add up to about 500-600 GB.

Within the database some operations may spill over to disk for want of enough work memory. E.g., a sort operation or a temp file. Thus, within a span
of say 1-2 seconds, a temp file may be created, written to, read back and then deleted. The temp file size I am guessing should seldom exceed 100MB.

Question - will the temp file in this scenario *necessarily* cause disk io? If not, how does one assess the likelihood? What parameters majorly influence this?

Comment: There will almost certainly be a small amount of disk I/O for the metadata. It's either managed synchronously or uses journals.

Comment: And the answer is "How long is a piece of string?" ... there are too many possible factors to ascertain whether or not it will be written to disk.  To make **sure** there's no disk I/O you could create a `tmpfs` of say 10GB. Of course, if THAT fills up you may be in trouble.

Comment: @barmar I will greatly appreciate if you could provide a link to read more.

Comment: Sorry, no idea where to find details. Why not use a ramdisk for the temp file?

Comment: @Barmar I do use a tmpfs. The question arose out of curiosity how IO subsystem works and would it actually eliminate a non-event like that. Thanks.

Comment: As @tink said, it's hard to predict, because it depends on what else needs the memory. It writes to disk if it needs to make some memory available for something else.

Comment: But metadata is usually forced to disk ASAP, to keep the filesystem consistent if there's a crash.